# NServiceBus persisting subscriptions in Pub/Sub sample

Tags: nservicebus

I want to figure out how I to set up the Pub/Sub sample from NServiceBus to work in the case of publisher malfunction.
When I start the samples and accidentaly close the Subscribers, if I restart everything works fine.
If however I kill the publisher and the subscriptions continue to work, if I restart the publisher, then it doesn't seem to know it has subscribers and doesn't post any messages.

I added the config entry
   <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig  Queue="subscriptions"/>
but it seems to not function... I miss something. I googled about MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig and DbSubscriptionStorageConfig but i didn't find a solution.

Could someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 4):

I found that a couple additional steps are required in order to get this working with the Pub/Sub sample under .Net 4.0, using a SQLite subscription storage system.

Combining the previous suggestions with the new ones, here are the required changes, all of which apply to the `MyPublisher` project.

---

- Add a reference to System.Data.SQLite.  Be sure to choose the version that matches your desired architecture (x86/x64).  These items can be found in the 'binaries' folder.
- In the `App.config` file, add the following as a new configSection element:

  ```
  <section name="DBSubscriptionStorageConfig" 
  type="NServiceBus.Config.DBSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  ```
- In the `App.config` file add, the following as a new configuration element:

  ```
  <DBSubscriptionStorageConfig>
      <NHibernateProperties>
          <add Key="connection.provider" 
              Value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
          <add Key="connection.driver_class"
              Value="NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver"/>
          <add Key="connection.connection_string"
              Value="Data Source=.\Subscriptions.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;"/>
          <add Key="dialect"
              Value="NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>
      </NHibernateProperties>
  </DBSubscriptionStorageConfig>
  ```
- Add this chunk of XML to the configuration section of the `NServiceBus.Host.exe.config` file:

  ```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the profile of the publisher to production. 
See http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles

For debugging this way, go to the properties of the publisher project, into the Debug tab, and put in NServiceBus.Production in the Command line arguments of the Start Options section.

Comment: I did that, added DB Subscription Storage found in the OrderService sample but I am stuck with the exception "Database was not configured through Database method." 

In the .config I used sqlite, I belive the sqlite file is not created. How do I set one up ?

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution. I missed the UpdateSchema property of the DBSubscriptionStorage node. This is the complete tag in order to work:

  <DBSubscriptionStorageConfig UpdateSchema="true">
    <NHibernateProperties>
      <add Key="connection.provider" Value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
      <add Key="connection.driver_class" Value="NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver"/>
      <add Key="connection.connection_string" Value="Data Source=.\Subscriptions.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;"/>
      <add Key="dialect" Value="NHibernate.Dialec...